# Adding row into excel via macro and generating UID

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an Excel workbook and I have a button to add new row at the top. The below starts at Row 4 (First data row is row 5). My actual sheet goes out to column L, but the below is just a few of the columns. The header row is highlighted grey. I had trouble with other examples of doing what I needed it to do, so I recorded a macro. Basically it copies the top data row, inserts it, removes highlight, and clears data. This way the lists I have are preserved as well as the cell borders. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Also, is there a way I can have the Add New Row button generate the UID for me? Note I may sort or filter the data, so I can't just take what's in A5 and add 1.

| UID | Requirement | Source | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0002 | ... | ... | [list] |
| 0001 | ... | ... | [list] |

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B5:L5").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Update 1:

New code based on everyone's recommendations. Still would be ideal if I could insert UID when I manually insert a row too.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Rows(5).Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    
    With Worksheets("Requirements")
        NextUID = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A")) + 1
    End With

    Range("A5").Value = NextUID
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `xlFormatFromRightOrBelow` as a second parameter of the method `Insert`.

Comment: Also, I don't think if there's any need to copy data. Just `Rows(5).Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromRightOrBelow`

Comment: Thank you the @Vitalizzare. This worked. I was confused as I was trying to set CopyOrigin to do the xlFormatFromRightorBelow previously.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Scott, get the maximum value of the first column and increment it:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    NextUID= WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A"))+1
End With
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, I would make it as a generator function with a static parameter to call Max once per session.

Comment: Thanks this worked @Donald-Koscheka!

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Rows(5).Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
    Range("A5").Value = NextUID
End Sub`

I was wondering if there is a way to make it insert a UID when I manually insert a row too?